# Need to understand COUNT() and multiple LEFT JOIN error in SQL code

Tags: sql, join, count, ms-access-2013

I am at a loss. Here is my code. I am trying to join three counts to RequestID. I can make them work individually (one join) but putting all three in the table is giving me duplication errors, where it counts more rows associated with the RequestID than are in the individual tables. I've been reading various posts but I haven't seen the light yet. I know there is something wrong with the arrangement or the order of joins that is causing the added info. I am doing a left join so I can capture 0's. Please help. Thank you.

```
SELECT RTable.RequestID, 
Count(sSentRequest.FileName) AS SentRequest, 
Count(sReceivedArticle.FileName) AS ReceivedArticle, 
Count(sMessages.FileName) AS Messages
FROM ((RTable 
LEFT JOIN sReceivedArticle ON RTable.RequestID =     
sReceivedArticle.FolderRQ) 
LEFT JOIN sSentRequest ON RTable.RequestID = 
sSentRequest.FolderRQ) 
LEFT JOIN sMessages ON RTable.RequestID = sMessages.FolderRQ
GROUP BY RTable.RequestID;
```

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant null values which end up interpreted as zeros in the table by default. I will be able to confirm if that does the trick on Monday.

Comment: Boyd P, that did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A LEFT JOIN doesn't capture 0s. It takes all the rows from the left table and looks for matching rows in the right table. If it doesn't find them, it returns NULL (which is different from 0).

Try this:

```
SELECT RTable.RequestID, 
(SELECT COUNT(FileName) FROM sSentRequest WHERE FolderRQ = RTable.RequestID) AS SentRequest,
(SELECT COUNT(FileName) FROM sReceivedArticle WHERE FolderRQ = RTable.RequestID) AS ReceivedArticle,
(SELECT COUNT(FileName) FROM sMessages WHERE FolderRQ = RTable.RequestID) AS Messages
FROM RTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is another possibility:

```
SELECT RTable.RequestID 
, COUNT(Nz(sSentRequest.FileName, 0)) AS SRCount 
, COUNT(Nz(sReceivedArticle.FileName, 0)) AS RACount 
, COUNT(Nz(sMessages.FileName, 0)) AS MsgCount 
FROM RTable 
  LEFT JOIN sSentRequest ON sSentRequest.FolderRQ = RTable.RequestID 
  LEFT JOIN sReceivedArticle ON sReceivedArticle.FolderRQ = RTable.RequestID 
  LEFT JOIN sMessages ON sMessages.FolderRQ = RTable.RequestID 
GROUP BY RTable.RequestID
```

Comment: This is also a good answer, and may perform better with joins, although I've seen subqueries which run much faster. Try both and pick the one which works more quickly. :)